# Golf scores python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create two programs one that writes the data to file golf.txt and the second which reads the records from golf.txt and displays them.  The first program I am trying to get the program to quit when you leave the input field blank.  Here's my code for the first program.

```
#Program that reads each player's name and golf score as input
#Save to golf.txt
outfile = open('golf.txt', 'w')

#Enter input, leave blank to quit program
while True:
    name = input("Player's name(leave blank to quit):")
    score = input("Player's score(leave blank to quit):")
    if input ==" ":
        break

#write to file golf.txt
outfile.write(name + "\n")

outfile.write(str(score) + "\n")

outfile.close()
```

With the second program I can't get the program to display the output I want on one line.  Here's the second program.

```
#Golf Scores

# main module/function
def main():

# opens the "golf.txt" file created in the Golf Player Input python
# in read-only mode
    infile = open('golf.txt', 'r')
# reads the player array from the file
    player = infile.read()
# reads the score array from the file
    score = infile.read()
# prints the names and scores

    print(player + "scored a" + score)

# closes the file    
    infile.close()

# calls main function
main()
```

Any help or suggestions I can get would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `if input == " "` will never work. You're comparing the function itself to a string, which will never return true. You want to compare the result of the function call to a string, eg, `if name == " " or score == " "`

Comment: it should be `if name == ''` since `'' != ' '` (empty fields for `input` returns a blank string, not a space string)

Comment: Next time you'll ask, please write one question per question, and post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `.read()` will read the whole file, not just one line. That's what's messing up the output of the second script. However you should also not be asking two questions in one post here. One question per post is the format of SO.

Comment: instead of dealing directly with text files, I'd advise you to serialize your data using some standard method, such as JSON using module [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). This way, instead of dealing with text, you can deal with native data structures, such as lists; see my answer to similiar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33697209/3821804).

Comment: Sorry was not aware that it was not okay to post two questions on one post.  Next time will only post one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got both programs working

program 1:

```
#Program that reads each player's name and golf score as input
#Save to golf.txt
outfile = open('golf.txt', 'w')

#Enter input, leave blank to quit program
while True:
    name = input("Player's name(leave blank to quit):")
    if name == "":
        break
    score = input("Player's score:")

#write to file golf.txt
    outfile.write(name + "\n")

    outfile.write(str(score) + "\n")

outfile.close()
```

program 2:

```
#Golf Scores

# main module/function
def main():

# opens the "golf.txt" file created in the Golf Player Input python
# in read-only mode
    infile = open('golf.txt', 'r')

# reads the player array from the file
    name = infile.readline()

    while name != '':

# reads the score array from the file
        score = infile.readline()

# strip newline from field
        name = name.rstrip('\n')
        score = score.rstrip('\n')
# prints the names and scores
        print(name + " scored a " + score)

# read the name field of next record
        name = infile.readline()

# closes the file    
    infile.close()

# calls main function
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Two main problems:

1.) you first code has `if input == ' '` which is wrong in two ways:

`input` is a function. you already saved the input so you should be comparing with `name` and `score`.

`input` returns a `''` when you dont input anything, not a `' '`.

so change to: `if name == '' or score == '':` or even `if '' in (name,score):` (does the same things)

2.) `file.read()` will automatically read EVERYTHING in the file as one string. You want to split it into each component so you can either do something like:

```
player,score = file.readlines()[:2]
```

or

```
player = file.readline()
score = file.readline()
```

then print (with leading and trailing spaces in your middle string!)

```
print(player + " scored a " + score)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, made a few changes and got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate spaces from the `input` before checking (I would use `.strip()` method). And compare it to the empty string `""` instead of space(s) `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

With the "while true" block you keep asking and taking the names and the scores, but you overwrite them so you always will have just the last pair.

You need to keep them all, so you can make a list:

```
names_and_scores = []

while True:
    name = input("Player's name(leave blank to quit):").strip()
    if name == "":
        break
    score = input("Player's score:").strip()
    if name != "" and score != "":
        names_and_scores.append("{}; {}".format(name, score))

with open('golf.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write("\n".join(names_and_scores))
```

The second program opens the file, read lines one by one, splits them and print:

```
with open('golf.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        name, score = line.strip().split("; ")
        print("{} scored a {}.".format(name, score))
```